# Flask/RabbitMQ: consume messages on a separate thread than the app

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, rabbitmq, thread-safety

I have a Flask microservice which serves user requests by an endpoint (say): `/getdata`

The data can be fetched in one of the two ways 1) cache or 2) from database directly - if the cache is in the process of being updated

Another service updates the database (thus making the cache stale). Once the service is done updating the database, it publishes a message to the rabbitmq stating: "update done"

Back to the microservice: I'd like it to have two threads: 
Thread 1: runs the `app.run()`

Thread 2: subscribes to the queue - where "update done" messages are published

Given the two threads, I don't want the `/getdata` to be fetching database from the cache when it's being updated. At the same time, I don't want to update the cache when data is being fetched from the endpoint.

Here's one solution I can think of:

1) Have a `threading.Lock()` as a "global"

2) `/getdata` checks if the lock is available; if so, it will acquire, fetch data from cache and release the lock. If the lock is unavailable, it will fetch the data from the database directly, thereby incurring a performance hit - but still getting the "latest" data

3) RabbitMQ "subscriber" checks the state of the lock; if so, it acquires the lock , updates the cache from the database and releases the lock. If not, it adds the request to a local "queue", and waits for say one minute before trying to acquire the lock again. When it does, it will pop the first item from queue and update the cache from the database.

My questions:

1. Given the multitude of libraries and options in Python/Flask - is
   there a library that allows me to do task like this in a "safe" way
   (I am using `pika` for rabbitmq access)
2. Is it possible to launch the flask app.run() via one thread and the
       queue subscriber via another (i.e. in `if __name__ == "main"`:
       )
3. How do I declare a "global" threading.Lock() which can coordinate
           the two threads?

Notes:

I expect that in the worse case the lock won't be acquired for more than one minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Pika is not thread safe. You should avoid sharing the connection object across Flask's contexts. Writing your own Flask plugin wouldn't take that much boilerplate though. It would be very similar to [the documentation example plugin](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/extensiondev/). Otherwise, you could do a quick search with `flask pika` on a search engine and you'll find some existing plugins for this purpose. I have not tried them and they don't seem really popular, but maybe you should give them a go?
2. I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. Flask knows how to deal with this. However, I reckon it would severly degrade performances. Moreover, you might hit some corner-cases if the plugins you use are not perfectly written.
3. Just like you would declare any lock for threading. Nothing much. You put it at the module level (not in Flask's context) so that it is global, that's it.

That being said, I think you shouldn't proceed this way. You should rather run the update-job in a different process from the Web Server (using Flask CLI or whatever if you need to re-use some functions). It will be better performance-wise, it's easier to reason about, it's more loosely coupled.

Also, you should avoid running into locking headaches as long as possible. Believe me, it's a real source of problems. It's a nightmare to test properly, to debug, to maintain and quite risky when it comes to real-production use-cases. And if you really, really need a lock, don't hold it for one minute, it's way too long.

I don't know your exact requirements, but there surely is a solution that is OK and that does not involve such complexity.